# Obtaining Linux host metrics from within a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, reporting, metrics

Looking for some recommendations for how to report linux host metrics such as cpu and memory utilization and disk usage stats from within a docker container. The host will contain a number of docker containers.  One thought was to run Top and other basic linux commands from the outside the container and push them into a container folder that has the appropriate authorization so that they can be consumed.  Another thought was to use the docker api to run docker stats for the containers but not sure this is the best as it may not report on other processes running on the host that are not containerized.  A third option would be to somehow execute something like TOP and other commands on the host from within the container, this option being the most ideal for my situation.  I was just looking for some proven design patterns that others have used. Also, I don’t have the ability to install a bunch of tools on the host as this would be a customer host which I don’t have control as to  what is already installed.

Comment: How about running a script on your host that spews system stats to a file and then mounting that file to the container?

Comment: yes, that was a thought also. The consensus of the group is to try to run it from within the container.

Comment: for the reason that customers will not allow scripts to be run and cron jobs created.  If we can do this from within the container and reach out of the container to the host to execute the top and a few other linux commands, that would suffice.

Comment: Running commands on the host defeats the purpose of containerizaton. You will have to run the container in privileged mode that could completely compromise the security

Answer (score 2):

You may run your container in **privileged** mode, but be aware  that it this could compromise the host security as your container will no longer be in a sandboxed environment.

```
docker run -d --privileged --pid=host alpine:3.8 sh
```

When the operator executes docker run --privileged, Docker will enable access to all devices on the host as well as set some configuration in AppArmor or SELinux to allow the container nearly all the same access to the host as processes running outside containers on the host. Additional information about running with --privileged is available on the Docker Blog.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities

Good reference: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/218379